# Adjust .cls latex class document

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing

I am trying to edit this particular .cls file

the only changes i want to make are those related to the front page, as can be seen from the picture. However the cls file is written in complex language and i cant figure out what to remove and yet be able to run it without errors or bad boxes.

[image]

Link to document [.cls](http://textuploader.com/d1b0c)

Link to text-document using this class "www.textuploader.com/d1b07" where the picture comes from

If i want to edit "Quantitative Finance, vol. 00. ..." as well. How would i do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. For LaTeX beginners it is not advisable to edit `.cls` files. There are other means. What do you mean by `complex` language? Where is the example file. The links point to the class only

Comment: It's not clear what you want to change. You want to remove the line at the very top, but do you want to *replace* that line with the circled stuff?  You don't need to change the class file itself to do that.

Comment: thats what i want to do.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to change the class file to do this, (and generally you shouldn't change class files) but you do need to understand a bit about the TeX language to make the changes.  Here's some code you can add to your document to make the changes instead of changing the class.

```
\documentclass{rQUF2e}
\usepackage{lipsum} % to provide dummy text
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\draftnote}{{\itshape \@jname} Vol. \@jvol, No. \@jnum, \ifx\@jmonth\empty\else\@jmonth\ \fi\@jyear,  \thepage--\@endpage}
\renewcommand{\ps@plain}{%
     \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
     \let\@oddfoot\@evenfoot
}
\makeatother

\title{A title}
\author{An author}
\affil{An affiliation}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

(The line is an artifact of the screen shot.)

[image]

Comment: aha so should fix it inside the .tex not the .cls